# seasonal_decompose in python over eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, statsmodels

I am trying to use the "seasonal_decompose" in statsmodels and even-though I explicitly installed ver 0.6.1 of the statsmodels package, when I try to run it (over eclipse) I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'seasonal_decompose'
```

Does someone know why this happens? Is there a chance that eclipse didn't get the version of the package despite the installation (it did ask me if to use the new version and I approved...) How do I check which module version do I have?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that updates of packages do not go well with eclipse, at least not with Luna over Anaconda. While the packages are accessible via python command line in Anaconda directory, they are not recognizable in eclipse. Redefinition of Anaconda (not upgrade, interpreter redef) in eclipse solves the problem.